# Item of ListView is cropped when GridLines is true and Explorer style is used

Tags: c#, winforms

I use ListView (WinForms) to show list of users. Property GridLines is true. Also I use Explorer style view for ListView.

```
SetWindowTheme(this.listView.Handle, "explorer", null);
```

In this case items of ListView are displayed incorrect. Items are cropped.

[image]

All is ok if property GridLines is disabled.
Is there way to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are they cropped??

Comment: He's probably complaining about the custom selection rectangle getting cropped.  Hmya, bummer, Explorer does not use grid lines.  Turn then off.

Comment: Take a look at selected item. Top selection border is visible, but lower border is cropped.